# How to make Timer.periodic cancel itself when a condition is reached?

Tags: dart

`Timer.periodic()` is great to have a function repeatedly execute, but is it possible to have the the timer cancel itself if an arbitrary condition is reached outside the function being executed by the timer?

Answer (score 62):

You get the timer passed into the callback. You can just call `cancel()` on it:

```
Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
  if(condition) {
    timer.cancel();
  }
});
```

or

```
Timer timer;

startTimer() {
  timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
    if(condition) {
      cancelTimer();
    }
  });
}

cancelTimer() {
  timer.cancel();
}
```

this way the timer can be cancelled independent of a timer event.

### Full non-nullable Dart example

```dart
import 'dart:async';

Timer? timer;
bool condition = false;

void main() async {
  startTimer();

  await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 600), () => condition = true);
}

startTimer() {
  timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), (timer) {
    print("condition: ${condition}");
    if (condition) {
      cancelTimer();
    }
  });
}

cancelTimer() {
  timer?.cancel();
  timer = null;
}
```

Comment: If I do option b, the Timer timer will always be null, even while the timer is running. it will run, but when i cancel it, it gives me a null exception

Comment: That's probably not related to the code in my answer. I guess cancel() is called before the timer is initialized.

Comment: You're kinda right, I did another thing wrong, you're code works fine

Comment: i get `Field '_timer' should be initialized because its type 'Timer' doesn't allow null.` when I try to follow this example.

Comment: This answer is from pre non-nullable Dart times. I updated it. Thanks for notifying!

Answer (score 5):

You could instead use `Stream.periodic` with `takeWhile`

```
  bool condition = true;

  Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () => condition = false);

  Stream.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1))
      .takeWhile((_) => condition)
      .forEach((e) {
    print('event: $e');
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution I found is to pass a function in to the timer that returns a `bool` and then use `timer.cancel()` when it's satisfied. Here's a generalized way of doing this:

```
periodically(int milliseconds, Function repeat, [Function cancel]) {
  return Timer.periodic(
    Duration(milliseconds: milliseconds),
    (Timer t) {
      repeat();
      if (cancel != null) {
        cancel() ? t.cancel() : null;
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// just using this code, with timer with stop if condition is reached
await Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 10), (timer) {
     pos += 10;
     if (pos > limit) {
       timer.cancel();
     }
     setState(() {});
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**I hope the above solution works fine for you but if not, then you can also try the below code because in my case the above solution does not works fine.**

```
 static Timer timerObjVar;
 static Timer timerObj;

   timerObj = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (Timer timer) async {
      timerObjVar = timer;
      _initData();  
   });
    
 // when you want to cancel the timer call this function
  cancelTimer() {

      if (timerObjVar != null) {            
        timerObjVar.cancel();
        timerObjVar = null;
      }

      if (timerObj != null) {           
        timerObj.cancel();
        timerObj = null;
      }
  }
```